# Kibana KQL search saved with time range

Tags: kibana

I'm creating a saved *search* using Kibana Discover. On screen I can select the time range manually (default is "Last 15 minutes"). If I select "Last 24 hours" and Refresh the search, it works fine. However, when I save the search, the time range information is not saved. Whenever I open Kibana Discover and open my saved search, the time range is always the default (last 15 minutes).

I tried adding different conditions (below) to my KQL query, to no avail.  :^(

```
 and @timestamp >= "now-24h"
 and @timestamp >= now-24h
 and timestamp >= "now-24h"
 and @timestamp >= "now-1d/d"
 etc.
```

I also tried to "Add filter" using the `@timestamp` field. The only operators available are: `is not`, `is one of`, `is not one of`, `is between`, `is not between`, `exists`, `does not exist`.
So, I tried `between` `now-24h` and `now`. Yet, no results match the criteria.

However, if I **manually** change the time range to say, Last 30 days, then my filter works!

[image: Kibana manual time range]

### Question

How do I include the time range, say *last 24 hours*, in my KQL saved search so that **it overrides the time range that is manually set on screen**?

(Motivation: I don't want to change the default manual time range to be larger than the range used in all saved searches. Also, I want to make the saved searches available to a support team with minimal manual configuration.)

(I'm using Kibana v7.10.0.)